# Should username of a deleted OP account be highlighted in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, display-names, deleted-accounts, highlighting

For example, take a look at this question: [Free web hosting for academics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/1200/14341)

User102 asked this question. They have deleted their account. But they are also the OP. Should their name be highlighted in their comments like any other questioner?

[image: image description]

Comment: I'm not sure what you ask. None of the user links are *highlighting*. Can you explain what you expect to happen or doesn't happen?

Comment: @Ooker did u mean to "gray" out the username?

Comment: @grgarside and that's why it's shown in "gray"color text without a link to profile, right?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want OP deleted users to still have their comment usernames highlighted blue to signify they *were* the OP. Am I right?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ yesssssss

Answer (score 2):

Meh. I don't think we need to do that.

I think (at least part) of the reason the name of the OP is highlighted is to enable easier conversation with the person the Q/A "belongs to." Once an account has been deleted, there isn't much purpose in writing comments to @ping them, as they won't respond.

Comment: But it would help later visitors identify who's who. At least for me. Knowing if the proposed solution helped the OP or not is also a value information.